# Using Jquery Tablesorter, how to make one of the columns the default one that sorts when the page loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 3 column table (name, author, and date).  When the page loads, it sorts the first column (name) by default.  How can I make it sort the 3rd column (date) by default when the page loads? Is it something to do with sortList?  Thanks for any help.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#SomeList").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]} ); 
    } 
);
```

---

```
$("#SomeList").tablesorter({ 
  widgets: ['zebra'],
  dateFormat: "uk",
  sortList: [[0, 0]], 
  headers: { 2: { sorter: false}} 
});
```

Comment: Your question has been answered but I would like to note that it would be more elegant to provide the data already sorted by date. That way you spare the initial sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also pass in configuration options when you initialize the table using the sortList argument:

> An array of instructions for per-column sorting and direction in the
>   format: [[columnIndex, sortDirection], ... ] where columnIndex is a
>   zero-based index for your columns left-to-right and sortDirection is 0
>   for Ascending and 1 for Descending. A valid argument that sorts
>   ascending first by column 1 and then column 2 looks like:
>   [[0,0],[1,0]]

Here's how to sort on the 3rd column

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
 // call the tablesorter plugin
 $("table").tablesorter({
     // sort on the third column, order asc
     sortList: [[2,0]]
 }); });
```

Reference:

[tablesorter - Set a initial sorting order](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-option-sort-list.html)

Comment: Thx for the useful configuration info.  That did the trick, works exactly how I wanted now. Thanks!