# jquery - Default column sort using tablesorter not working

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have a sortable table that's working fine. All I want to do is make it sort a default column by default on page load. I went to the plugins documentation on http://tablesorter.com/docs/ used the exact same code that is there showing an example of just what I'm trying to do, but for some reason, it isn't working. What I'm using is below:

`$(".tablesorter").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,1], [1,1]]} );`

I also read this: [Using Jquery Tablesorter, how to make one of the columns the default one that sorts when the page loads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993740/using-jquery-tablesorter-how-to-make-one-of-the-columns-the-default-one-that-so)

It's essentially the same thing.

I'm not getting any console errors either. Has anyone else ever had this problem or know why it wouldn't be working?

Edit:
Here's what I basically have that currently sorts, but doesn't default to the given sortList value http://jsfiddle.net/86Ta2/

Comment: I added external resources to [your demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/86Ta2/2/), and it works, so I'm not sure what might be causing problems. I also wanted to share that I have a [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) that includes a [foot-inch-fraction parser](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-feet-inch-fraction.html) that you might find useful.

Comment: I had it working too, so there was some sort of code conflict. I got it working in a janky way by using a timeout before it loads. So the page loads and then the tablesorter loads. Thank you for all of that  info :)

Answer (score 0):

you might be doing something wrong in your code, share the code with us to take a look at it, create a http://jsfiddle.net

here is a working example based on the docs

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // call the tablesorter plugin 
    $("table").tablesorter({ 
        // sort on the first column and third column, order asc 
        sortList: [[0,1],[1,1]] 
    }); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d55Td/

Comment: I got it working on jsfiddle, so it must be conflicting with something on the page. I hate working with someone else's code :/